# Addition using printf in C

Tags: c, math, printf

on net: using `printf` to add two numbers(without using any operator) like following:

```
main()
{
    printf("Summ = %d",add(10,20))
    return 0;
}

int add(int x,int y)
{   
    return printf("%*d%*d",x,' ',y,' ');
}
```

Could anyone please explain, how this works:

```
return printf("%*d%*d",x,' ',y,' ');
```

Note: This fails when i call "sum" like following:

```
sum(1,1) or sum(3,-1)
```

Comment: Do not know...Why this is not working for each and every input...for example "sum(1,1)"..Do I need to modify the code for each and every input.If this is the case, then this logic is wrong.

Comment: I would've gone with `char dummy; return snprintf(&dummy, 1, "%*s%*s", x, "", y, "");` instead to avoid useless output.

Comment: Your function in the upper code is `add`.  Then your question is about the function `sum`.   Those are *different* functions.

Answer (score 8):

There are two central concepts here:

1. `printf()` returns the number of characters printed.
2. The `%*d` format specifier causes `printf()` to read two integers from its arguments, and use the first to set the field width used to format the second (as a decimal number).

So in effect the values being added are used as field widths, and `printf()` then returns the sum.

I'm not sure about the actual `d` formatting of the space character, at the moment. That looks weird, I would have gone with an empty string instead:

```
static int sum(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return printf("%*s%*s", a, "", b, "");
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int a = 13, b = 6;
    int apb = sum(a, b);

    printf("%d + %d = %d?\n", a, b, apb);

    return 0;
}
```

The above works and properly computes the sum as `19`.

Comment: @cHao Well sure, but of course I'd print it as a string too, with `s`. See the code. I just think this is clearer.

Comment: Yeah, saw the update.  That makes more sense.  :)

Comment: Well, `' '` is an `int`, so the `%d` formatting will print `32`. And since the field width is a minimum (meaning that the output will not be truncated if it is larger than the specified width), `add(1,1)` will return `4`. Your solution with `%*s` and `""` is thus much better (although the trick won't work with negative numbers of course).

Comment: @Virgile That was kind of my point, but thanks for spelling it out. :) I made `sum()` take `unsigned int` args instead to make it clear it won't work with negative numbers, well spotted.

Comment: Thanks for response...Its not working when adding one "+ve" and one "-ve" number.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` returns the number of printed characters.

Here, it is used in the `add` function to generate a string only composed of `10` + `20` spaces, by using the format string.

So the `printf` in the `add` function will return `30`.

Then, this result is simply printed with printf (his main purpose).

*Note: it might be evident, but this `printf` usage has to be avoided. It's very dirty as it generates useless outputs. Imagine: `add(10000,10000)`...*

Answer (score 1):

First, `printf` returns the number of characters it prints.

Second, in the format specifier `%*d`, `*` means the minimum number of characters to be printed, but the width is not from the format string itself, but from the additional argument.

With all together, the job is done, but it won't work well on small numbers like `1` because of `%d` in the format specifier, a better solution could be :

```
("%*c%*c", a, ' ', b,' ');
```